# php - why is my query not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I just created a .php file, unfortunately my sql query is not working on my web hosting but the .php file is working perfectly. so the problem is, my sql query is failing to be executed

It says:

> Post Gagal or Post failed (in english)

can you tell why I have an sql error and how to fix this error

> this my php code

```
                        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
            ob_start();
             session_start();
            require 'connection.php';

             // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
             if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
              header("Location: loginpanel.php");
              exit;
             }
             // select loggedin users detail
             $res=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM akun_admin WHERE idadmin=".$_SESSION['user']);
             $userRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

            if ( isset($_POST['btn-post']) ) {
                $error = false;
              // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
              $jd = trim($_POST['jd']);
              $jd = strip_tags($jd);

              $sa = trim($_POST['sa']);
              $sa = strip_tags($sa);

              $note = trim($_POST['note']);
              $note = strip_tags($note);

              $genre = trim($_POST['genre']);
              $genre = strip_tags($genre);

              $ps = trim($_POST['ps']);
              $ps = strip_tags($ps);

              $ep14 = trim($_POST['1Link480p']);
              $ep17 = trim($_POST['1Link720p']);
              $ep1 = trim($ep14.'-'.$ep17);
              $ep1 = strip_tags($ep1);

              $ep24 = trim($_POST['2Link480p']);
              $ep27 = trim($_POST['2Link720p']);
              $ep2 = trim($ep24.'-'.$ep27);
              $ep2 = strip_tags($ep2);

              $ep34 = trim($_POST['3Link480p']);
              $ep37 = trim($_POST['3Link720p']);
              $ep3 = trim($ep34.'-'.$ep37);
              $ep3 = strip_tags($ep3);

              $ep44 = trim($_POST['4Link480p']);
              $ep47 = trim($_POST['4Link720p']);
              $ep4 = trim($ep44.'-'.$ep47);
              $ep4 = strip_tags($ep4);  

              $ep54 = trim($_POST['5Link480p']);
              $ep57 = trim($_POST['5Link720p']);
              $ep5 = trim($ep54.'-'.$ep57);
              $ep5 = strip_tags($ep5);

              $ep64 = trim($_POST['6Link480p']);
              $ep67 = trim($_POST['6Link720p']);
              $ep6 = trim($ep64.'-'.$ep67);
              $ep6 = strip_tags($ep6);

              $ep74 = trim($_POST['7Link480p']);
              $ep77 = trim($_POST['7Link720p']);
              $ep7 = trim($ep74.'-'.$ep77);
              $ep7 = strip_tags($ep7);

              $ep84 = trim($_POST['8Link480p']);
              $ep87 = trim($_POST['8Link720p']);
              $ep8 = trim($ep84.'-'.$ep87);
              $ep8 = strip_tags($ep8);

              $ep94 = trim($_POST['9Link480p']);
              $ep97 = trim($_POST['9Link720p']);
              $ep9 = trim($ep94.'-'.$ep97);
              $ep9 = strip_tags($ep9);

              $ep104 = trim($_POST['10Link480p']);
              $ep107 = trim($_POST['10Link720p']);
              $ep10 = trim($ep104.'-'.$ep107);
              $ep10 = strip_tags($ep10);

              $ep114 = trim($_POST['11Link480p']);
              $ep117 = trim($_POST['11Link720p']);
              $ep11 = trim($ep114.'-'.$ep117);
              $ep11 = strip_tags($ep11);

              $ep124 = trim($_POST['12Link480p']);
              $ep127 = trim($_POST['12Link720p']);
              $ep12 = trim($ep124.'-'.$ep127);
              $ep12 = strip_tags($ep12);

              $ep134 = trim($_POST['13Link480p']);
              $ep137 = trim($_POST['13Link720p']);
              $ep13 = trim($ep134.'-'.$ep137);
              $ep13 = strip_tags($ep13);

              $ep144 = trim($_POST['14Link480p']);
              $ep147 = trim($_POST['14Link720p']);
              $ep14 = trim($ep144.'-'.$ep147);
              $ep14 = strip_tags($ep14);

              $ep154 = trim($_POST['15Link480p']);
              $ep157 = trim($_POST['15Link720p']);
              $ep15 = trim($ep154.'-'.$ep157);
              $ep15 = strip_tags($ep15);

              $ep164 = trim($_POST['16Link480p']);
              $ep167 = trim($_POST['16Link720p']);
              $ep16 = trim($ep164.'-'.$ep167);
              $ep16 = strip_tags($ep16);

              $ep174 = trim($_POST['17Link480p']);
              $ep177 = trim($_POST['17Link720p']);
              $ep17 = trim($ep174.'-'.$ep177);
              $ep17 = strip_tags($ep17);

              $ep184 = trim($_POST['18Link480p']);
              $ep187 = trim($_POST['18Link720p']);
              $ep18 = trim($ep184.'-'.$ep187);
              $ep18 = strip_tags($ep18);

              $ep194 = trim($_POST['19Link480p']);
              $ep197 = trim($_POST['19Link720p']);
              $ep19 = trim($ep194.'-'.$ep197);
              $ep19 = strip_tags($ep19);

              $ep204 = trim($_POST['20Link480p']);
              $ep207 = trim($_POST['20Link720p']);
              $ep20 = trim($ep204.'-'.$ep207);
              $ep20 = strip_tags($ep20);

              $ep214 = trim($_POST['21Link480p']);
              $ep217 = trim($_POST['21Link720p']);
              $ep21 = trim($ep214.'-'.$ep217);
              $ep21 = strip_tags($ep21);

              $ep224 = trim($_POST['22Link480p']);
              $ep227 = trim($_POST['22Link720p']);
              $ep22 = trim($ep224.'-'.$ep227);
              $ep22 = strip_tags($ep22);   

              $ep234 = trim($_POST['23Link480p']);
              $ep237 = trim($_POST['23Link720p']);
              $ep23 = trim($ep234.'-'.$ep237);
              $ep23 = strip_tags($ep23);

              $ep244 = trim($_POST['24Link480p']);
              $ep247 = trim($_POST['24Link720p']);
              $ep24 = trim($ep244.'-'.$ep247);
              $ep24 = strip_tags($ep24);

              $tp = date("Y-m-d");
              $wp = date("h:i:sa");

              $ap = $userRow['alias'];

            function generateRandomString($length = 50) {
                $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
                $randomString = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
                }
                return $randomString;
            }
              $postID = generateRandomString();
              // if there's no error, continue to signup
              if(!empty($jd)) {
               $res = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO postperepisode1_12 (idpost, judulpost, tanggal, waktu, adminposting, genre, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1`, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, note, sinopsis) VALUES ('$postID', '$jd', '$tp', '$wp', '$ap', '$genre', '$ep1', '$ep2', '$ep3', '$ep4', '$ep5', '$ep6', '$ep7', '$ep8', '$ep9', '$ep10', '$ep11', '$ep12', '$ep13', '$ep14', '$ep15', '$ep16', '$ep17', '$ep18', '$ep19', '$ep20', '$ep21', '$ep22', '$ep23', '$ep24', '$sa', '$note')");

               if ($res) {
                $errTyp = "success";
                $errMSG = "Posting Berhasil";
               } else {
                $errTyp = "danger";
                $errMSG = "Post Gagal"; 
               } 

              }


             }
            ?>
```

Comment: Since the PHP code works well, it could be a database error. Put this in your else statement to check `echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: Are you sure column name is correct?  16, 1`, 18

Comment: that wrong, i just edited to `16,17,18`, but is still not working

Comment: can you show us connection.php as well?

Comment: Add this code at top your page to display detail error: error_reporting(~0);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: `<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "(i can't tell this)";
$password = "(i can't tell this)";
$dbname = "id2140800_fuyami";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>`

Comment: not make any changes @DT

Comment: Are you running by Browser?

Comment: ok good, your connection is proper. Last question, can you tell me which query causing problem? SELECT query or INSERT?

Comment: i use Chrome sir @D T

Comment: on `INSERT` query sir @ParagSoni

Comment: I think, order column not correct:note, sinopsis  '$sa', '$note'

Comment: Okay, Now test your query. After `if(!empty($jd)) {` store your query as `$query = 'YOUR QUERY';` and after that `die($query);` So you can get your query string, Copy this and run this directly into database. so mysql will show you which line causing error, If query work well there then problem is in tour connection credentials.

Comment: Thanks, i have edited it. It turns out, mysql rows can not be named by number `1,2,3, etc`. They should still be given by text `a1, a2, a3, etc` and that worked ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes，i see ,but it is your custom error, maybe you can print your sql and excute in
 mysql client. you can check the mysqli_error($conn) firstly

Comment: Thanks, i have edited it. It turns out, mysql rows can not be named by number `1,2,3, etc`. They should still be given by text `a1, a2, a3, etc`. Thank you for your suggestion, that fix it ^_^